# How do you view PostgreSQL messages (such as RAISE NOTICE) in DBeaver?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I think this is a DBeaver UI/Configuration question, but I cannot see where the messages are when executing a script (Alt-X).

In PGAdminIII, I would execute a script and see the `NOTICE` output:
[image]

In DBeaver, the same script does not output in "Statistics" tab.  But I am not certain if this is where I should be looking for the messages:
[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On DBeaver 5.2.0 you can use Ctrl+Shif+O or the button Show server output console on the left side of the script window.

[image]

Comment: thanks. i'm embarrassed that I didn't see that!

Comment: I didn't see it either, don't be embarrassed